# How to use one function variable in another function of same class in openerp?

Tags: python, odoo, postgresql-9.1

I have one variable var_x in fct1.
I want to use same variable value in another function fct2 in same class
Code:

```
def onchange_blockcreate(self, cr, uid, ids, block):
    global family_code_id
    global varname        
    if block:
        cr.execute ('select activefrom,activeto from new_block where id=%s ',(block,))            
        family_code_id =cr.fetchone()[0]               
    msgalert = {'title':'Warning','message':}
    return {'warning':msgalert}
def onchange_evaluation_date(self, cr, uid, ids,family_code_id,activefrom):
    print activefrom
    print family_code_id
    if activefrom>=family_code_id:
        print activefrom          
    else :
        msgalert = {'title':'Warning','message':'fieldtocheck is too short!'}
        return {'warning':msgalert}
```

Here family_code_id is used in first function ,I want to use same family_code_id in second function also. But it shows an error:

> global variable family_code_id is not defined.

How is this possible in openerp?

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code. Use 4 spaces per indent. Don't mix tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could use global variables, but there's usually a better way.

My first suggestion would be to pass the `family_code_id` field into both `on_change` events. Are you worried that it will change in the client between the two calls? If not, just add a `family_code_id` parameter to the `onchange_blockcreate()` method, and add `family_code_id` to the list of fields in your XML file's `on_change` attribute.

If you're determined to use a global variable, you probably need to declare it global in both methods, and assign it in the `onchange_evaluation_date()` method. Global variables are generally a bad idea, and class member variables are usually better. OpenERP model classes are singletons, though, so you usually don't want to hold any state. Everything should come in through method parameters.

Comment: Thanks for help don.i got more idea

Answer (score 0):

you have to define that variable in  class Lable

Like ---->    global family_code_id    as well as in  class label  then  it work properly

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the variable inside the class and you can retrive that data in any of the functions inside the class by calling self.variable_name